# minicom throwing an error minicom: cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, nvidia-jetson, minicom

I have tried to connect my Jetson Nano with TTL UART cable using minicom. When I typed

```
sudo minicom
```

It showed an error

```
minicom throwing an error minicom: cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 12):

sudo is always a way...

What minicom tells you with this message that it has tried to open a interface called `/dev/modem`. It is telling you, that it can't be opened due to insufficient permissions.

On my system `/dev/modem` does not even exist! Anyhow, minicom expects in it's settings the `/dev/modem` as default. That's why it's trying to connect to that.

So, the solution is `minicom -s`, where you actually enter the settings of minicom. Here you'll find the the settings to properly configure your board. If you run this with sudo, you are able to also save your settings, if you want to. You might want to change those settings to e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0` or something.

Comment: Thanks, just would like to mention the option to configure the port straight away `minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0`

Answer (score 7):

Later I tried with

```
sudo minicom -s
```

It worked

Comment: Ty, @ShaikAhmad. For completeness - the next step for me was to go to Serial port setup and change the Serial Device from `/dev/modem` to something else, like `/dev/ttyS0` for the serial port, for example.